# How to generate reST/sphinx source from python?

Tags: python, documentation-generation, restructuredtext, python-sphinx

I'd like to generate documentation via reST, but don't want to write the reST source manually, but let a python script do that and then produce other formats (HTML, PDF) with sphinx.

Imagine I have a telephone book in binary format. Now I use a python script to parse this and generate a document with all the names and numbers:

```
  phone_book = PhonebookParser("somefile.bin")

  restdoc = restProducer.NewDocument()
  for entry in phone_book:
    restdoc.add_section( title = entry.name, body = entry.number )

  restdoc.write_to_file("phonebook.rst")
```

Then I would go on to invoke sphinx for generating pdf and html:

```
  > sphinx phonebook.rst -o phonebook.pdf
  > sphinx phonebook.rst -o phonebook.html
```

Is there a python module (aka restProducer in the example above) that offers an API for generating reST? Or is the best way to just dump reST markup via a couple of print statements?

Comment: Can you explain what format you'd like to generate the reST format from?

Comment: Basically from internal state of the program. I have got some hashes and lists and now it would like to iterate thru these and maybe generate a section in a document for each entry in these data structures.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. See [Automatically Generating Documentation for All Python Package Contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616693/automatically-generating-documentation-for-all-python-package-contents/4617804#4617804).
2. The upcoming [Sphinx 1.1](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/latest/changes.html) release includes a [sphinx-apidoc.py](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/src/ce4bb37a1409/sphinx-apidoc.py) script.

EDIT:

Now that you have explained the problem a bit more, I'd say: go for the "dump reST markup via a couple of print statements" option. You seem to be thinking along those lines already. Why not try to implement a minimalistic `restProducer`?

Comment: It is not a python module or package I'd like to document. The python script just has some knowledge it should format into a reST source.

Comment: @dantje: where does the "knowledge" come from?

Comment: The application reads other files, parses them and should then produce a documentation.

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with the inner workings of Sphinx, but it looks like it uses another library, "docutils" (http://docutils.sourceforge.net/), to help with parsing from the reST. You can take a look at that library and see what it's doing.

Comment: I'll try to implement a restProducer myself and make use of a templating engine like jinja2.

Answer (score 4):

If you want docs-without-writing-docs (which will at best give you an API reference rather than real docs), then the [autosummary](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/autosummary.html) and [autodoc](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/autodoc.html) extensions for Sphinx may be what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is to programmatically compose the document once, and be able to output in multiple formats, you could have a look at QTextDocument in PyQt Framework. It is an overkill, though.

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys

doc = QTextDocument()
cur = QTextCursor(doc)

d_font = QFont('Times New Roman')
doc.setDefaultFont(d_font)

table_fmt = QTextTableFormat()
table_fmt.setColumnWidthConstraints([
    QTextLength(QTextLength.PercentageLength, 30),
    QTextLength(QTextLength.PercentageLength, 70)
    ])
table = cur.insertTable(5,2, table_fmt)
cur.insertText('sample text 1')
cur.movePosition(cur.NextCell)
cur.insertText('sample text 2')

# Print to a pdf file
# QPrinter: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
printer = QPrinter(QPrinter.HighResolution)
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
printer.setOutputFileName('sample.pdf')

# Save to file
writer = QTextDocumentWriter()
writer.setFormat(writer.supportedDocumentFormats()[1])
writer.setFileName('sample.odt')
writer.write(doc)
```

[QTextDocumentWriter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextdocumentwriter.html#supportedDocumentFormats) supports plaintext, html and ODF. [QPrinter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprinter.html#OutputFormat-enum) can be used to print to a physical printer or to a PDF file.

However, templating engines like Jinja2 as you mentioned is a neater way to do it.