# Django Sphinx automodule -- basics

Tags: python, django, documentation, python-sphinx, sphinx-apidoc

I have a project with several large apps and where settings and apps files are split.

directory structure goes something like that:

**project_name**

- _*init*_.py
- apps
- _*init*_.py
- app1
- app2
- 3rdparty
- _*init*_.py
- lib1
- lib2
- settings
- _*init*_.py
- installed_apps.py
- path.py
- templates.py
- locale.py
- ...
- urls.py

**every app is like that**

- _*init*_.py
- admin
- _*init*_.py
- file1.py
- file2.py
- models
- _*init*_.py
- model1.py
- model2.py
- tests
- _*init*_.py
- test1.py
- test2.py
- views
- _*init*_.py
- view1.py
- view2.py
- urls.py

How to use a Sphinx to autogenerate documentation for that?

I want something like that
for each in settings module or INSTALLED_APPS (not starting with django.* or 3rdparty.*) give me a auto documentation output based on docstring.

And autogen documentation and run tests before git commit

btw.
I tried doing .rst files by hand with

```
.. automodule:: module_name
   :members:
```

but is sucks for such a big project,
and it does not works for settings

Is there an autogen method or something?

I am not tied to Sphinx, is there a better solution for my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. See [Automatically Generating Documentation for All Python Package Contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616693/automatically-generating-documentation-for-all-python-package-contents/4617804#4617804).
2. The upcoming [Sphinx 1.1](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/changes.html#release-1-1-oct-9-2011) release includes a [sphinx-apidoc.py](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/src/ce4bb37a1409/sphinx-apidoc.py) script.

Answer (score 1):

[**django-sphinx-autodoc**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-sphinx-autodoc) will probably be of help here.

From the documentation:

> #### How it works
>
> Copy the `generate_autodoc.py` file in your project directory, then
>   execute it.
>
> It will scrape all your `.py` files in each application listed by
>   `INSTALLED_APP`, then add automodules in your `DS_ROOT/modules.rst`.
>
> You will then see your applications grouped in 2 different categories:
>
> - *internal application* is an application located in your project
>     directory
> - *external application* is an app which is somewhere in your
>     pythonpath (preferably in your virtualenv)
>
> #### Good Practices
>
> Add a docstring in your application's `__init__.py` file to describe it.
>   django-sphinx-autodoc will automatically scrape it for you.

Comment: Sadly, that seems to be abandonware.