# Structuring Sphinx documentation

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have started documenting a Python project using Sphinx. It is the first time I use it - I am used to tools which work with a JavaDoc-like syntax, and I have some doubts.

Since I want the documentation to appear near the code, I make use of the `.. automodule::`, `.. autoclass::` and `.. automethod::` directives. So the structure of my documentation is as follows: `index.rst` contains the TOC and

```
.. automodule:: my_main_package
```

and then the top-level `__init__.py` contains directives like

```
.. automodule:: some_subpackage
```

for each subpackage and so on. Finally each module contains directives

```
.. autoclass:: some_class
    :members:
```

for each class in the module.

This mostly works, but what I get is a single page documentation, which is a little odd to work with.

> How should I organize my documentation in order to obtain a tree of hyperlinked files? That is, the main package should contain its own documentation and links to each of its subpackages and so on, until each module has its own page.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found this [autopackage script](https://bitbucket.org/etienned/sphinx-autopackage-script) from a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616693/automatically-generating-documentation-for-all-python-package-contents/4617804#4617804). It generates the necessary .rst files according to the structure of your packages.

*side note: I still feel I am missing something, as I cannot believe that a tool like Sphinx, which is renowned as the most advanced tool for documenting Python, misses the functionality to do basic API documentation. Hence I will leave the question open for a while before accepting my own answer.*

Comment: Just ran across this question myself. I feel like I'm missing something as well. But this is a huge violation of the DRY principle. Why am I duplicating my entire module structure in .rst files?

Comment: note, that script is now an integral part of Sphinx known as apidoc: http://sphinx-doc.org/man/sphinx-apidoc.html

Answer (score 3):

Even I am not an expert in this, but I think I can answer what you have asked here(about having the organization of the documentation/ rst files).

The key you may be missing here is instead of using the autoclass/automodule/automethod calls in the same top level `TOC`s rst-file, this top level file should contain links to other rst files containing these calls.

suppose you have all rst files inside `doc` dir (and subdirs),

```
Table of contents
=================
The contents of the docs are:

.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 1

    module_1/index
    module_2/index
```

in the dir containing this top level `index.rst`, you will have subdirs with name `module_1` and `module_2`. These will have `index.rst` (name is just example specific) which in turn will contain the `.. automodule::`, `.. autoclass::`, and `.. automethod::`. It can contain something like

```
:mod:`module_1`
---------------

..automodule:: module_1
    :show-inheritance:

.. autoclass:: module_1.MyClass
```

Of course, this is not something like standard, or ideal way of doing, I am suggesting this because it's neater. you can alternatively have all the rst files with module/class/method docs in the same dir as the top level index.rst, with structure

```
Table of contents
=================
The contents of the docs are:

.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 1

    module_1
    module_2
```

and the same dir will contain the doc-files `module_1.rst`, `module_2.rst` etc. The paths are **relative** to the `config.py` file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but if understand well this means replicating the module structure in a bunch of rst files, which is far from ideal. The point of my question is how to let Sphynx find this on its own, which is the task of the script I have linked.

Comment: @Andrea Well I think, replicating structure isn't necessary, its just my taste, python docutils and rst allows us to make any structure, we just need to include links. Maybe I didn't understand your question properly, but with whatever I have understood, maybe you shouldn't include `.. automodule::` in your index.rst.

Comment: Well, the question is the following. I have a python package including API documentation in Sphynx format. I want to be able to extract this documentation, but I do not want to have to manually create a rst file for each python file - I think this should be the task of Sphynx itself. How can I do this? In my answer, for instance, I link a script that does this task. If I understand correctly your answer, you suggest to do this manually

Answer (score 0):

I am by no means an expert on Sphinx, but from reading the [documentation](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/tutorial.html#defining-document-structure) it seems that you can include TOC trees in subdirectories.  [The TOC tree page](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/markup/toctree.html#toctree-directive) also gives some information on paths within the tree; have you experimented with using paths in the tree?

Comment: I am not an expert either, so I may be missing something really basic. But if I understand this correctly, in order to use the TOC I should create a bunch of .rst files. So I have to duplicate the structure. Instead I'm not creating additional .rst files: all the documentation is in the Python source. Please correct me if I misunderstood your reply.