# Including source in Sphinx documentation

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am trying to use Sphinx to document a Python project of mine, but I am struggling with the differences between this tool and the usual tools like JavaDoc which are meant to document an API. Of course I see that Sphinx has many more uses than documenting an API, but it seems to be lacking in the simpler task.

I [have managed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319210/structuring-sphinx-documentation) to find out how to let Sphinx know about your package structure, so that you do not have to manually replicate it into ReST files. My next problem is:

> Is it possible to include a link to the source for all classes with Sphinx?

Of course the source should be nicely formatted, but since Sphinx uses pygments I don't think that is a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [sphinx.ext.viewcode](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/viewcode.html).

Answer (score 0):

Include a extension in conf.py.

```
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.viewcode']
```