# sphinx-apidoc usage - multiple source python directories

Tags: python, python-sphinx, sphinx-apidoc

So I have my python source files in two different directories:-

e.g.

```
~/work/myproject
~/.virtualenvs/myproject
```

How do I use `sphinx-apidoc` to look in both directories recursively to generate my reST files?

Obviously,

```
sphinx-apidoc -o docs/source ~/work/myproject
```

works perfectly fine but when I attempt to run

```
sphinx-apidoc -o docs/source ~/.virtualenvs/myproject
```

again, sphinx tells me that "docs/source/modules.rst already exists, skipping" which of course is true as I have already run `sphinx-apidoc` once to generate it.

So how do I execute it once and search in both directories?

Comment: You can have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616693/automatically-generating-documentation-for-all-python-package-contents

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Sphinx apidoc documentation](http://sphinx-doc.org/man/sphinx-apidoc.html), the commandline syntax is:

```
sphinx-apidoc [options] -o <outputdir> <sourcedir> [pathnames ...]
```

**Update: wrong**, see comment by @jgbarah below.

This means that if you want to document sources in two separate directories, you *can* pass both directories/pathnames at once, so something like:

```
sphinx-apidoc -o docs/source ~/work/myproject ~/.virtualenvs/myproject
```

**Improved suggestion**:

You could make a subdirectory inside your documentation per project. So something like:

```
sphinx-apidoc -o docs/source/app1 ~/work/myproject1
sphinx-apidoc -o docs/source/app2 ~/work/myproject2
```

With a toctree you could then point at the two subdirectories:

```
.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 2

    app1/index.rst
    app2/index.rst
```

Comment: No. According to [Sphinx-apidoc man page](http://sphinx-doc.org/man/sphinx-apidoc.html),  Any pathnames given are paths to be excluded from the generation. So, i guess that won't work...