# Sphinx ignoring imports (py2.7)

Tags: python-2.7, python-sphinx

Sphinx seems to be ignoring imports in autodoc'ed modules.

**doc/conf.py excerpt**

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)
```

**doc/code.rst**

```
Auto Generated Documentation
============================

Utils
-----

.. automodule:: myproject.utils
   :members:
```

**myproject/utils/__init__.py**

```
from data import *
from hashing import *
from redis import *
from cookie import *
from route import *

def method_whose_docstring_is_picked_up(string):
    """I'm being autodoc'ed. =)
    """
```

None of the classes or functions from X import Y are being autodoc'ed. Anything directly in the `__init__.py` is being picked up just not the imports. I tried explicitly importing each object but that didn't resolve anything.

Comment: Does it work if you add an `__all__` list? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/30856279/407651

Comment: "An option to automodule is either unknown or has an invalid id value: '__all__' ". Doesn't seem to.

Comment: `__all__` is not an option to `automodule`, it is a variable that can be added to `__init__.py` (see https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is possible with the imported-members but it will also drag in all std-lib and third-party imports as well, cluttering up your sphinx doc.

[Sphinx, using automodule to find submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508290/sphinx-using-automodule-to-find-submodules)