# Using Sphinx to automatically generate a separate document for each function

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I've been building a Python module with many different functions.

I'm using Sphinx and readthedocs to provide documentation.  I've made decent progress, but currently I have [one massive page](https://epidemicsonnetworks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/EoN.html) that gives the documentation for all of my functions (in alphabetical order).

I've looked at other projects which have a separate page for each function.  In looking through their source, I find a separate .rst file has been created for each.  I assume this is done automatically, and [this page](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autosummary.html) on generating autodoc summaries seems like it's describing some of this, but I just can't make sense of it.

[`sphinx-apidoc`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/man/sphinx-apidoc.html) has an option (-e) to create a page for each module, but I want one for each function.

How does one use Sphinx to automatically generate a separate page for each function?

---

**additional information**

To add info for one of the answers below, I've put the following into my `EoN.rst` file, which sits in the subdirectory `docs`.

```
EON documentation
=================

.. automodule:: ../EoN
   :members:

.. currentmodule:: ../EoN

.. autosummary::
   :toctree: functions

   fast_SIR
   fast_SIS
```

I get the error message

```
$ sphinx-autogen -o docs/generated docs/*.rst
```

> [autosummary] generating autosummary for: docs/index.rst, docs/methods.rst, docs/quickstart.rst
>
> [autosummary] writing to docs/generated
>
> WARNING: [autosummary] failed to import u'fast_SIR': no module named fast_SIR
>
> WARNING: [autosummary] failed to import u'fast_SIS': no module named fast_SIS

`fast_SIS` and `fast_SIR` sit within `../EoN.py`

Comment: What other projects have you looked at that have a separate page for each function?

Comment: @mzjn see https://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/algorithms.html

Comment: That documentation uses the same approach with autosummary as I suggest in my answer. See https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/v1.11/doc/source/reference/algorithms.bipartite.rst

Comment: `.. automodule:: ../EoN` is ill-formed. The argument to that directive or to the `currentmodule` directive should be a "dotted module name", such as simply `EoN` or `mypackage.EoN`. `../EoN` is not a correct module name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the answer to [Sorting display by class using sphinx with 'autodoc'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14606348/407651) it is explained how to generate documentation for classes with one page per class, using [autosummary](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autosummary.html) with `autosummary_generate=True`.

This mechanism works for functions too. Use something like this:

```
EoN API documentation
=====================

.. currentmodule:: EoN

.. autosummary::
   :toctree: functions

   my_function1
   my_function2
   my_function3
   ...
```

You have to enumerate each function in the `autosummary` directive, but the corresponding *.rst files are generated automatically (in the `functions` subdirectory).

Comment: Getting an error when I try that - `WARNING: [autosummary] failed to import u'fast_SIR': no module named fast_SIR`

I've edited the question showing exactly how I've implemented your answer (too much information to squeeze into a comment).

Comment: I'm still not having luck.  It's giving an error that it can't find the module `EoN.my_function1`.  Which of course it can't because it's a function.  Could it be related to the fact that your answer in the linked question included a template?

Comment: I don't think the template is the problem. When no `template` option is given, the default template is used: [autosummary/base.rst](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autosummary.html#customizing-templates).

Comment: I found your project on GitHub. The `currentmodule` argument should be `EoN.simulation` for autosummary to work. And there should be a blank line immediately after `:toctree: functions` (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EpidemicsOnNetworks/EpidemicsOnNetworks/master/docs/methods.rst).

Comment: I've put up the most recent attempt up on github. If you look at my docs/documentation.rst, I believe everything you've said is in place. But I continue to get the error "failed to import 'EoN.simulation.fast_SIR': no module named EoN.simulation.fast_SIR" when that is the function I want to get.

Comment: You must add the `sphinx.ext.autosummary` extension to the `extensions` variable in conf.py.

Comment: Likely that last thing was the solution.  At any rate, sphinx-autogen continues to give me that error message but sphinx-autobuild is now creating the files I want (it's possible I missed them being created a step or two earlier since I was focused on the error message from sphinx-autogen).

Answer (score 11):

I think the [sphinx-automodapi](http://sphinx-automodapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) Sphinx extension may do what you need. Essentially to document a module you would just do:

```
.. automodapi:: mypackage.mymodule
```

and it will generate the table and individual pages for each function.

*Disclaimer: I am an author of sphinx-automodapi*

Comment: Hi @astrofrog - it looks like this has been useful to people, but I haven't tried it - mostly because I don't know where to put this line.  Can you tell me exactly what I should be doing?  (and fwiw, my package is at https://github.com/springer-math/Mathematics-of-Epidemics-on-Networks if that helps you fine-tune any advice)

Comment: @Joel - you would need to put ``extensions = ['sphinx_automodapi.automodapi']`` in ``conf.py``, and ``.. automodapi:: EoN`` inside ``index.rst``.

Comment: This package is seriously awesome. Thank you for sharing it. I used `.. automodsumm:: module`, `:toctree: api` to make a table without separate function/class sections.

Comment: I like the use of `automodapi`, but was curious if there is a way to specify the classes that should be displayed. Basically the opposite of `:skip: str` (which allows us to remove unnecessary entries); is there any option to specify what we want included?

I see that this is possible via `autosummary`, but given a choice, I would like to use `automodapi`.

Comment: Finally! This is what I was looking for! It was really hard to find it, though. Thank you very much @astrofrog