# sphinx-autogen unable to find module

Tags: python-sphinx

I'm trying to implement one of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43357912/2966723).  However, I haven't been successful because when I run

```
> sphinx-autogen -o generated  *.rst
```

I get the errors

> Failed to import 'MyMod.X': no module named MyMod.X
>
> Failed to import 'MyMod.Y': no module named MyMod.Y
>
> Failed to import 'MyMod.Z': no module named MyMod.Z

Within my `.rst` files, there is one with the line:

> .. automodule:: MyMod.X

(and similarly for `MyMod.Y` and `MyMod.Z`).

I'm running this within a subdirectory `docs`.  In the parent directory containing `docs`, there is also a subdirectory `MyMod` which contains `__init__.py`, `X.py`, `Y.py`, and `Z.py`.  The `conf.py` file within `docs` has the line `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../'))` immediately after `import sys`.

The closest related question I can find is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324393/sphinx-build-fail-autodoc-cant-import-find-module), but the answers there seem to suggest that it is solved by inserting `'../'` into the path, which I had already done.  Also, `sphinx-autobuild` can find these modules happily, so I don't think this is the issue.

Interestingly, changing the line in my `.rst` file to be `.. automodule:: ../MyMod.X` gets rid of the error message, though nothing seems to be generated in the directory I expect, and I then get error messages in `sphinx-autobuild`.

How can I get `sphinx-autogen` to read in these modules?

Comment: I can reproduce the error with sphinx-autogen. But when I set `autosummary_generate = True` in conf.py and run sphinx-build instead, it works.

Answer (score 0):

**if anyone else has a better answer, or an explanation for this please post it, but here is what I learned about my question**

Although `sphinx-autogen` gives error messages, in the case that I was looking at, the files I was trying to get it to create were still created.  While it could not find the modules (and indeed, they were functions, not modules, so it's not a surprise that it couldn't), it still produced the expected output.