# Using autosummary_generate = True with readthedocs

Tags: read-the-docs

I have been trying to publish some documentation and can't get it to work. From what I can tell it looks to me as if `readthedocs` is ignoring the `autosummary_generate = True` directive in `conf.py`

I am using `autosummary` and it works well on my local machine, with all the individual `.rst` files being generated when calling make html.

When building on readthedocs everything appears to work, with no errors being thrown, but when trying to browse the documentation the links do not work. Digging a bit deeper I see this type of warnings:

```
/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/libgs-ops/checkouts/latest/docs/source/index.rst:23: WARNING: failed to import libgs_ops.propagator
```

Since that is a file that should be generated by autosummary I am assuming the problem is, as I mentioned, that readthedocs has not generated the files.

You can experience the problem for yourselves here;
https://libgs-ops.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

See how none of the links work.

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43357912/using-sphinx-to-automatically-generate-a-separate-document-for-each-function/43373428?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C31.3264#43373428), in which someone references a similar problem in one of the responses, but as the problem asked appears to be different I permit myself to create this new thread. As I said, autosummary works fine on my local install, just not on readthedocs.

Comment: I have the exact same problem and would really appreciate an answer to this.