# How can I get Sphinx autosummary to generate full API documentation for classes, as well as a *summary table* for those classes?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm sure this is user error at one level or another but I'm going mad slowly here and would really appreciate some help.

I've gotten both [`sphinx-apidoc`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html) and the excellent third party [`sphinx-autoapi`](https://sphinx-autoapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to work, but can't repeat the trick with [`sphinx.ext.autosummary`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autosummary.html). It's driving me mad... plus neither of these options give you the really neat package/module member summary tables that are (presumably) the main selling point of `sphinx.ext.autosummary`.

I have a really simple project:

```
|_ TEST
   |_ docs
      |_ conf.py
      |_ index.rst
   |_ myproject
      |_ __init__.py
      |_ mymodule.py
```

`conf.py` looks like this:

```py
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../myproject'))

extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.autosummary'
]

autosummary_generate = True
```

`index.rst` looks like this:

```
.. autosummary::
   :toctree: _autosummary

   myproject.mymodule
```

`mymodule.py` looks like this:

```py
"""
Module containing a class and a function.
"""

class TestClass:
    """
    A class representing a test.

    I wish I could get this to stuff to show up but I can't and I don't know why.

    Why isn't this documentation visible?!? :-(
    """
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Instantiate.
        """
        pass

    def Func_in_test_class(self):
        """
        Cool function that does stuff.

        :return: Some new stuff.
        """
        pass

def GlobalFunc():
    """
    Utility function.

    Does some good stuff.
    """
    pass
```

Running `make html` from the `docs` directory makes this lovely Readthedocs-style HTML:

[image: (see picture)]

What I want to do is click on the `TestClass` function in the summary table and visit a new page that shows the API documentation for this class in full. How can I achieve that?

(Or am I missing the point, and I have to combine `sphinx.ext.autosummary` with `sphinx-apidoc` to get what I need..?)

Comment: If your project really is that simple, I wonder if it wouldn't be easier to just create the needed RST markup "by hand" instead of using sphinx-apidoc. Maybe this is what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14621772/407651

Answer (score 4):

From Sphinx version 3.1 (June 2020), `sphinx.ext.autosummary` finally has recursion!

I've answered my own question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62613202/12014259

Comment: It seems as though python 2.7 is only supported up to Sphinx 1.8.6, which means it does not support recursion.