# Use Sphinx autosummary recursively to generate API documentation

Tags: python, jinja2, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, toctree

I want to use Sphinx's [autosummary extension](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autosummary.html) and [templates](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/templating.html) to generate API docs recursively from docstrings. I want separate pages for each module, class, method, property and function. But it doesn't detect my templates at all. In fact, if I just remove the `module.rst` file from `_templates/autosummary/`, it renders the whole file exactly the same way as before. I've followed [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21665947/774273) to the letter. If you're interested, [the full repository is on GitHub](https://github.com/nils-werner/sparse/tree/docs).

Edit: It seems it does generate a different file, I had to delete docs/_autosummary for it to read the new template. However, now it generates a file with the `sparse` header and `description` header. It doesn't go into the `{% if classes %}` and `{% if functions %}` directives.

My directory structure is as follows:

- sparse
- docs

  - conf.py
  - index.rst
  - modules.rst
  - _templates/autosummary/module.rst

Here are the relevant files so far:

`index.rst`:

```
.. sparse documentation master file, created by
   sphinx-quickstart on Fri Dec 29 20:58:03 2017.
   You can adapt this file completely to your liking, but it should at least
   contain the root `toctree` directive.

Welcome to sparse's documentation!
==================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

   modules

Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

`modules.rst`:

```
API Reference
=============

Modules
-------

.. autosummary::
   :toctree: _autosummary

   sparse
```

`_templates/autosummary/module.rst`:

```
{{ fullname | escape | underline }}

Description
-----------

.. automodule:: {{ fullname | escape }}

{% if classes %}
Classes
-------
.. autosummary:
    :toctree: _autosummary

    {% for class in classes %}
        {{ class }}
    {% endfor %}

{% endif %}

{% if functions %}
Functions
---------
.. autosummary:
    :toctree: _autosummary

    {% for function in functions %}
        {{ function }}
    {% endfor %}

{% endif %}
```

Comment: Why don't you use [sphinx-apidoc](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/man/sphinx-apidoc.html)?

Comment: If sphinx-apidoc can do something similar to what I want (with templates and member summaries), then I shall. Unfortunately I'm not too good with Sphinx and an example would be useful. But as I understand it, sphinx-apidoc is equivalent to using autosummary with `autosummary_generate = True`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From Sphinx version 3.1 (June 2020), you can use the new `:recursive:` option to get `sphinx.ext.autosummary` to automatically detect every module in your package, however deeply nested, and automatically generate documentation for every attribute, class, function and exception in that module.

See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62613202/12014259

Answer (score 13):

I ended up needing the following files:

`modules.rst`:

```
API Reference
=============

.. rubric:: Modules

.. autosummary::
   :toctree: generated

   sparse
```

`_templates/autosummary/module.rst`:

```
{{ fullname | escape | underline }}

.. rubric:: Description

.. automodule:: {{ fullname }}

.. currentmodule:: {{ fullname }}

{% if classes %}
.. rubric:: Classes

.. autosummary::
    :toctree: .
    {% for class in classes %}
    {{ class }}
    {% endfor %}

{% endif %}

{% if functions %}
.. rubric:: Functions

.. autosummary::
    :toctree: .
    {% for function in functions %}
    {{ function }}
    {% endfor %}

{% endif %}
```

`_templates/autosummary/class.rst`:

```
{{ fullname | escape | underline}}

.. currentmodule:: {{ module }}

.. autoclass:: {{ objname }}

   {% block methods %}
   {% block attributes %}
   {% if attributes %}
   .. HACK -- the point here is that we don't want this to appear in the output, but the autosummary should still generate the pages.
      .. autosummary::
         :toctree:
      {% for item in all_attributes %}
         {%- if not item.startswith('_') %}
         {{ name }}.{{ item }}
         {%- endif -%}
      {%- endfor %}
   {% endif %}
   {% endblock %}

   {% if methods %}
   .. HACK -- the point here is that we don't want this to appear in the output, but the autosummary should still generate the pages.
      .. autosummary::
         :toctree:
      {% for item in all_methods %}
         {%- if not item.startswith('_') or item in ['__call__'] %}
         {{ name }}.{{ item }}
         {%- endif -%}
      {%- endfor %}
   {% endif %}
   {% endblock %}
```

`_templates/autosummary/base.rst`:

```
{{ fullname | escape | underline}}

.. currentmodule:: {{ module }}

.. auto{{ objtype }}:: {{ objname }}
```

I also needed to go to `sphinx/ext/autosummary/generate.py` and set `imported_members=True` in the function `generate_autosummary_docs`.

If you're not using `numpydoc` like me, you might need to remove the `.. HACK` directives.

Comment: I cloned your GitHub project and it worked for me too. Setting `imported_members=True` in the `generate_autosummary_docs` function seems to be the key. But it is problematic that it should be necessary to edit the Sphinx source code to make it work.

Comment: I just saw https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/4372. You have `__all__ = ["COO", "tensordot", "concatenate", "stack", "dot", "triu", "tril"]` in `__init__.py` and that should be enough IMHO. As far as I can tell, `autosummary` does not take `__all__` into account.

Comment: Yes, it should either take `__all__` into account or provide a way to include imported members.

Comment: Great answer, very helpful! Are you aware of a way to add the documented module attributes (like constant definitions) to the output in modules.rst?

Comment: @mar10 You would add an attributes section similar to the functions and classes section in `_templates/autosummary/module.rst`. I haven't tried it myself, but I'm pretty sure it will work.

Comment: @HameerAbbasi `attributes` seems to be empty, but `members` has content. I can filter out like `if item not in all_functions and item not in all_classes ...` and get mostly what I want (except for imported module names and symbols, which I did not figure out how to exclude)