# How to generate Python package documentation with Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, toctree

Currently I do this:

conf.py:

```
autosummary_generate = True
```

reference.rst:

```
package_1
---------
.. autosummary::
   :toctree: _generated

   package_1.module_1
   package_1.module_2
   package_1.module_3
   ...
```

This will generate an overview table for each module, with entries for each module 
that nicely link to detail pages.

I have two questions:

1. Do I really have to enumerate every single module?
2. How can I control the options of the detail pages?

Ad 1.: 
I would like to do s.th like this (which currently doesn't work):

```
.. autosummary:: package_1
   :toctree: _generated
   :members:
```

(Or maybe a new `autopackage` command.)

Ad 2.: 
I would like to pass options like the ones that `automodule` or `autoclass` expect, e.g.:

```
.. autosummary::
   :toctree: _generated
   :undoc-members:
   :private-members:
```

This seems to be an obvious task, so I am probably missing some information.
Is there an easy alternative way to accomplish this?

Comment: Have a look at [`sphinx-autogen`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/ext/autosummary.html#sphinx-autogen-generate-autodoc-stub-pages) to generate stub pages in rST, from which you would generate your docs. There's a similar toolchain with [sphinx-apidoc](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html) and [autodoc](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/ext/autodoc.html).

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48074094/407651

Comment: @StevePiercy as I understand it, `autosummary_generate = True` is equivalent (http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/ext/autosummary.html#confval-autosummary_generate)

Comment: @mzjn You're right: the question you linked to is similar. It offers a solution to the 'Ad 2.' part of my question. Would you suggest that creating a custom template is the way to go (looks a bit complicated to me, but anyway)?

Comment: @mar10 I don't know what, if any, differences there may be between the two, so I don't know if they are equivalent. Suggest trying both to compare and contrast, as divining the differences from reading documentation is tedious. TBH, this is the first time I've seen sphinx-autogen.

Comment: @mar10 I can't think of anything else. It is unfortunate that autosummary doesn't accept more options.

Comment: Thank you all for your time and comments, I summarized my solution in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all commenters!

**Ad 1:**
I list the modules manually.

**Ad 2:**
I finally went with the solution proposed by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48074094/407651) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21665947/19166) answers to similar questions:

Create template files (`_templates/autosummary/module.rst` and `_templates/autosummary/class.rst`) and add this to
**api_doc.rst:**

```
Package ``wsgidav``
-------------------
.. autosummary::
   :toctree: _autosummary

   wsgidav._version
   wsgidav.compat
```