# Create class overview in sphinx like epydoc

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx, epydoc

Epydoc, which has long since ceased development, used to offer an extremely powerful overview of a class or module. For example, this:

[image]

Notice it shows the classes within the module with the first line or so of the doc-string. For functions it shows the function prototype as well with the start of the doc-string and optional arguments spelled out.

This is incredibly useful when browsing the documentation because one can look in rationally named classes/modules and easily find an appropriate function or method.

I'd like to have this similar feature in Sphinx but I cannot not find any example which demonstrates this. Frankly, I'm a little surprised because in all of the sea of praise of Sphinx, no one seems to care about this feature being absent, or at least absent as far as I can tell.

Does anyone know if there is a way to replicate something like the shown image in Sphinx?

Comment: Does [`sphinx-autodoc`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/ext/autodoc.html) not solve your issue?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding but its not the discovery of python modules thats the issue, it's the manner in which the discovered documentation and function/modules/classes/etc are displayed.

Comment: It is possible to get something similar with Sphinx using `autosummary`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/14606348/407651.

Comment: Here is another question which is about creating a more automatic setup: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48074094/407651

Comment: That auto summary approach looks very very promising.