# Get autosummary to produce a flat representation

Tags: python-sphinx, numpydoc, autosummary

If I have a file `foo.baz.py`:

```
from foo.bar.baz import Quux, Quuux

__all__ = ['Quux', 'Quuux']
```

I'd like to document the api as follows:

```
Baz
===

.. currentmodule:: foo.baz

.. autosummary::
   :toctree: generated/
   :nosignatures:

   Quux
   Quuux
```

This gives me an autosummary table with `Quux` and `Quuux`, and links to pages containing their full documentation. However, it requires me to explicitly list `Quux` and `Quuux`, so whenever I add a class, I have to manually add it to the documentation.

Instead, I'd rather like to do something like this, and have it automatically generate a table based on `__all__`, to get exactly the same output as above:

```
Baz
===

.. currentmodule:: foo

.. autosummary::
   :toctree: generated/
   :nosignatures:

   baz
```

But this doesn't work, it produces a table with a single entry, the module `baz`, leading to a page with all its contents as well as a summary table.

Is there a way to achieve this? In case it's relevant, I'm using `numpydoc`.

Comment: Perhaps you can use `autosummary` with the `recursive` option: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62613202/407651

Comment: @mzjn I've tried that, but I don't see how