# Sphinx autosummary without new page

Tags: python-sphinx, autosummary

Using sphinx's autodoc extension, the `autosummary` functionality produces a link towards a new page with all modules in a table.

Is there any way that the produced table can be put inside the current page, without the link?
Someone pointed in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68192892/get-autosummary-to-produce-a-flat-representation) to use the `:recursive:` functionnality but that still produces a new page to the table.

Currently in the file `mypage.rst`, I have:

```
.. currentmodule:: package
.. autosummary::
    :toctree: generated
    :recursive:

    module
```

and the resulting files in `module` are displayed through a link named `module`.