# How do I exclude modules from autosummary recursive documentation

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autosummary

I have some Sphinx docs like so:

```
Browse the code-based documentation here:

.. autosummary::
   :toctree: _autosummary
   :template: custom-module-template.rst
   :recursive:

   foo
```

Where `foo` is a module which has `foo.bar`, `foo.bar.a`, `foo.baz`, etc. Is there a way to exclude `foo.baz`?

Comment: I found this to be a pain as well. My experience with Sphinx, so far, has been that most feature are useless, and the most useful features... are not there.

Answer (score 2):

On the custom-module-template.rst template, at the part were it iterates through the submodules you can add an if statement to check the name of the module, like so:

```
{# rest of the module template #}

{% block modules %}
{% if modules %}
.. rubric:: Modules

.. autosummary::
   :toctree:
   :template: custom-module-template.rst
   :recursive:
   {% for item in modules %}
   {% if not item.endswith('.baz') %}
       {{ item }}
   {%- endif %}
   {%- endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I'm not sure this is the best solution, but this works for me.

Hint for the [custom-module-template.rst](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62613202/4981674)