# Sphinx recursive autosummary not importing modules

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs, autosummary

I'm going crazy with Sphinx's recursive autosummary. My working directory is:

```
my_wd
|
|-- docs
|   |-- source
|      |--index.md
|      |--conf.py
|      |-- _templates
|          |-- custom-module-template.rst
|          |-- custom-class-template.rst
|-- my_library
|   |-- several .py modules
```

at the top of `conf.py`is:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../..'))
```

in `index.md` I have:

````
```{toctree}
:caption: 'Contents:'
:maxdepth: 2

Home <self>

```

```{include} ../../README.md
:relative-images:
```

```{eval-rst}
.. autosummary::
   :toctree: _autosummary
   :template: custom-module-template.rst
   :recursive:
   
   my_library
```
````

and the files `custom-module-template.rst` and `custom-class-template.rst` are filled according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62613202/6231251).

Still, the autosummary is not working. In the log I first get

```
[autosummary] generating autosummary for: _autosummary/module1.rst, _autosummary/module2.rst...
```

(which doesn't seem right: why is it looking for rst files?)

Then I get

```
WARNING: [autosummary] failed to import my_library.
    Possible hints:
    * ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
    * ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_library'
    * KeyError: 'my_library'
    
failed to import my_library.module
```

for every `module.py` that is included in the `my_library` folder.

This means (I guess) that sphinx is actually seeing the different `.py` modules in the `my_library` folder (but it's then looking for the corresponding rst files?!). So the absolute path *should* be right.

This sounds like a path error to me, but I think the path is right.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` in `my_library` to make it a Python package? Sphinx can only import Python packages. [`autosummary`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autosummary.html) generates autodoc summary files. Then you use `autodoc` to create HTML docs. You also might need to specify the valid file extensions that MyST looks for when using `autosummary`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with __init__.py. If any of your modules import from other modules in the same package, you'll get this error and I don't know what the solution is. Driving me crazy as well.