# Sphinx's autosummary with recursive option is not being fully recursive

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, autosummary

I am using Sphinx to document a Python project, which has the structure tree depicted below.

```
calculator
|   set_rho_and_f.py
|   set_rho_and_V_dot.py
|
├───data
│   ├───fans
│   │       ...
│   │
│   ├───functions
│   │       ...
│   │
│   └───systems
│           ...
|
├───docs
│   ├───build
|   |       ...
|   |
│   └───source
|           ...
|
├───results
|       ...
│
└───src
        fans.py
        functions.py
        systems.py
```

[**Note**: The coding project comprises `set_rho_and_f.py` and `set_rho_anf_V_dot.py` files, and `data`, `results` and `src` folders. The ellipses "..." represent content (directories and files) that has been herein omitted for the sake of compactness.]

I wanted to create a summary page using all docstrings in the project. In `conf.py` file I then added the `autosummary` extension:

```py
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.autosummary'
]
autosummary_generate = True
```

And in the reStructuredText file for the summary, I wrote

```
Summary
=======

.. autosummary::
   :toctree: _autosummary
   :recursive:

   data
   results
   src
   set_rho_and_f
   set_rho_and_V_dot
```

When getting an HTML file after doing `make html`, I experienced that even though `autosummary` can go through files inside a folder (just look at `src` section in the picture below) it cannot go through files inside subfolders of a folder (just look at `data` section in the picture below, which is missing `data/fans`, `data/functions` and `data/systems` sections).

[image]

Is this a typical behaviour of the `autosummary` directive? Is there any option to make it indeed go through the whole content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Self-answering:**

After having a look at the [Git Hub repository](https://github.com/JamesALeedham/Sphinx-Autosummary-Recursion) mentioned in [James Leedham' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62613202/4382986) for how to automatically document all content recursively with Sphinx, I found out that by adding an `__init__.py` file to the subdirectories, the respective content is included in the summary generated by `autosummary` (as shown in the picture below).

It seems like that in this way `autosummary` interpreted the subdirectories as packages, which are then parsed as objects that may be documented under the `autosummary` scope.

[image]