# Sphinx autosummary only adding __init__ methods for classes

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc, autosummary

I am trying to use Sphinx autosummary to document all of the classes within the directory `mypackage/src/`. Sphinx is only generating proper documentation for the class constructors but none of the (public) methods inside classes. What am I doing wrong?

### Project structure:

```
 - docs/
     - build/
     - source/
        - _static/
        - generated/
            - mypackage.src.file_3.ClassInsideFile3.rst
        - api.rst
        - conf.py
        - index.rst
        - usage.rst
    - make.bat
    - Makefile
- mypackage/
    - __init__.py
    - file_1.py
    - file_2.py
    - src/
        - __init__.py
        - file_3.py
        - file_4.py
- tests/
- .gitignore
- poetry.lock
- pyproject.tomml
- README.md
```

### `docs/source/conf.py`:

```py
# Configuration file for the Sphinx documentation builder.
#
# For the full list of built-in configuration values, see the documentation:
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html

# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#project-information

import sys
import os


sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../..'))

project = 'mypackage'
copyright = '2023 My Name'
author = 'My Name'
release = '0.1.0'

# -- General configuration ---------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#general-configuration

extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc', 'sphinx.ext.autosummary']

templates_path = ['_templates']
exclude_patterns = []

# -- Options for HTML output -------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#options-for-html-output

html_theme = 'alabaster'
html_static_path = ['_static']
```

### `docs/source/api.rst`:

```
API
===

src
---
.. autosummary::
   :toctree: generated
   :recursive:
   
      mypackage.src.file_3.class_inside_file_3
```

### `mypackage/src/file_3.py`:

```py
class ClassInsideFile3:
    "Docstring for the class"
    def __init__(self, names: list):
        """
        Initializes a ClassInsideFile3 object based on names argument
        
        :param names: A list of names
        :type names: list
        """
        self.names = names

    
    def add_name(self, name: str) -> None:
        """
        Appends a new name to the list of names if it does not already exist
        
        :param name: The name to be appended 
        :type name: str
        """  
        if name not in self.names:
            self.names.append(name)
```

### The result I get when I run `sphinx-build docs/source docs/build`:

[image]

### The generated file `docs/source/generated/mypackage.src.file_3.ClassInsideFile3.rst`:

```
mypackage.src.file_3.ClassInsideFile3
=====================================

.. currentmodule:: mypackage.src.file_3

.. autoclass:: ClassInsideFile3

   
   .. automethod:: __init__
   # Why isn't it creating an auto method for `add_name`?

   
   .. rubric:: Methods

   .. autosummary::
   
      ~ClassInsideFile3.__init__
      ~ClassInsideFile3.add_name
```

Why isn't Sphinx creating an auto method for the `add_name` method?

Comment: The output that you get is consistent with the class.rst template: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/master/sphinx/ext/autosummary/templates/autosummary/class.rst

Comment: [Templates can be customized](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autosummary.html#customizing-templates). See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62613202/407651.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding `:members:` under autoclass to specify you want all documented members? (cf. https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#directive-option-automodule-members)

My "standard" setting (here for automodule, but autoclass should behave in a similar way):

```
.. automodule:: mymodule
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :special-members: __len__
```

Comment: I am using the autosummary:: extension - I am able to get it working with autoclass:: although that will require me to continue to refactor my documentation instead of using :recursive: with autosummary::

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't notice that your last file is auto-generated.